# How to convert int[][] string to List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, junit5

There is a string like "`[[7], [2,2,3]]`".

How can I convert this string to a `List<List<Integer>>` Object?

This is to implement a parameter converter in JUnit5.

```
@CsvSource({
    "'[2,3,6,7]', 7, '[[7], [2, 2, 3]]'"
})
```

I want to convert the string "`[[7], [2,2,3]]`" to a `List<List<Integer>>` Object.

Comment: Is it actually an `int[][]` array or a string that you want to convert ?

Comment: convert  `string` to `List<List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

you split your input string at `], [` which gives you following rows:

```
row[0]: [[7
row[1]: 2,2,3]]
```

then you eliminate the `'[['`  `']]'` strings

```
row[0]: 7
row[1]: 2,2,3
```

then you iterate over the elements of the rows by splitting them further at `','` and add each element to a list. When you are finished with one row you add it to the list of the listOfLists.

```
public List<List<Integer>> parseList(){
    String s  = "[[7], [2,2,3]]";

    return Arrays.stream(s.split("], \\["))
      .map(row -> row.replace("[[", "").replace("]]", ""))
      .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row.split(","))
        .map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList())
      ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I assume you meant to convert a given `int[][]` (or `Integer[][]`) and not parsing a `String`.

You can use a conventional for-loop or the stream API (since Java 8) for that.

There are actually a lot of variants to achieve this.

---

### Stream

Assuming your `source` array is of type `int[][]`:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = Arrays.stream(source)     // Stream<int[]>
    .map(Arrays::stream)                               // Stream<IntStream>
    .map(IntStream::boxed)                             // Stream<Stream<Integer>>
    .map(values -> values.collect(Collectors.toList()) // Stream<List<Integer>>
    .collect(Collectors.toList())                      // List<List<Integer>>
```

Assuming it is of type `Integer[][]`:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = Arrays.stream(source)     // Stream<Integer[]>
    .map(Arrays::stream)                               // Stream<Stream<Integer>>
    .map(values -> values.collect(Collectors.toList()) // Stream<List<Integer>>
    .collect(Collectors.toList())                      // List<List<Integer>>
```

In case you are okay with the inner arrays being immutable (you can not add or remove items to them):

```
List<List<Integer>> result = Arrays.stream(source)     // Stream<Integer[]>
    .map(Arrays::asList)                               // Stream<List<Integer>>
    .collect(Collectors.toList())                      // List<List<Integer>>
```

---

### Loop

Here is the variant for a conventional enhanced for loop:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(source.length);
for (int[] innerValues : source) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(innerValues.length);
    for (int value : innerValues) {
        values.add(value);
    }
    result.add(values);
}
```

If `source` is `Integer[][]`, just replace `int` with `Integer` in the above code.

You can also use `forEach`:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(source.length);
for (int[] innerValues : source) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(innerValues.length);
    innerValues.forEach(values::add);
    result.add(values);
}
```

Or `values = Arrays.asList(innerValues)`. But then they are immutable again.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Java 8 stream API this way:

```
Integer[][] dataSet = new Integer[][] {{...}, {...}, ...};
List<List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(dataSet)
                               .map(Arrays::asList)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Note that the inner lists are immutable. It is not possible to edit them. If that is not allowed, you have to explicitly collect the inner arrays into lists as well (instead of using `Arrays.asList`).

Comment: The title of the question hints that OP uses `int[][]` and not `Integer[][]`. Your code will not work with that, as it is written now.

Answer (score 1):

If input is string, then you can parse it using JSON Library.

Following code converts string to the output you are expecting.

```
JSONArray obj = (JSONArray) new JSONObject("{ \"array\" : [[7],[2,2,3]] }").get("array");

List<Object> list = obj.toList();
List<ArrayList<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

list.forEach(item -> {

    ArrayList<Integer> ar = (ArrayList<Integer>) item;

    newList.add(ar);
});

System.out.println(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert 2-d Integer array to `List<List<Integer>>` by using:

```
private static List<List<Integer>> arrayToList(Integer[][] array) {
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer[] a : array) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
        lists.add(list);
    }
    return lists;
}
```