# How to convert nested array to nested list using lambda?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

**Update**:
use `Integer[][]` as as src array type could make the following code work.

---

I want to convert `int[][]` to `List<List<Integer>>` and tried with:

```java
int[][] arr = new int[][]{{2}, {3, 4}, {6, 5, 7}, {4, 1, 8, 3}};
List<List<Integer>> ll = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(Arrays::asList) //  I expect this produces Stream<List<Integer>> but it was actually a Stream<List<int[]>>.
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the compiler emits an error:

```
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
|      equality constraints: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
|      lower bounds: java.util.List<int[]>
|          List<List<Integer>> ll = Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::asList).collect(Collectors.toList());
|                                   ^-----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: @Naman I don't see how this question is a duplicate of any of the linked questions.

Comment: @hev1 Did you go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58338259/1746118)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` doesn't work with primitives (at least, not in the way you intend: `Arrays.asList(new int[n])` is a `List<int[]>` with one element, not a `List<Integer>` with `n` elements).

Instead, map to an `IntStream` (to give you an `IntStream`), box the elements (to give you a `Stream<Integer>`), and collect to a list (to give you a `List<Integer>`:

```
List<List<Integer>> ll = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .map(a -> IntStream.of(a).boxed().collect(toList()))
    .collect(toList());
```

---

Note that if you're using Guava, you could use [`Ints.asList`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html):

```
List<List<Integer>> ll = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .map(Ints::asList)
    .collect(toList());
```

Other libraries may well also have `int[] -> List<Integer>` methods; this is merely one I know exists.